# How to redirect mobile version to computer version using .Htaccess

Tags: redirect, mobile, subdomain

I have edited .Htaccess in public html to redirect my subdomain  Mobile version (m.domain.com). I want my mobile version (m.domain.com) to be redirected to the automatic computer version ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) if anyone visits the computer with the subdomain (m.domain.com)

Comment: can you please post your code in the question?